# Azure SSIS Package - Execute SQL Task

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I have created a simple SSIS package with "Execute SQL Task". When I am trying to execute the package in Azure, it fails with the below error:

> Error: Failed to acquire connection "my connection". Connection may
>   not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions
>   on this connection.
>
> Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "Login timeout expired". An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not
>   found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information
>   see SQL Server Books Online.". An OLE DB record is available.  Source:
>   "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005 
>   Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server [53]. ".

However, it works fine when I run it with some other task. Can someone tell me what could be the issue? I am guessing SSIS package execution from Azure does not support "Execute SQL Task".

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, where the SQL task query data from, on-premise SQL Server?

Comment: can you please elaborate works fine when I run from some other task

Comment: @LeonYue The SQL task queries data from Azure SQL Managed Instance. I am using SSIS-Runtime Integration that uses a self hosted managed instance as proxy.

Comment: @VenkataramanR Instead of SQL Task, I have used a Data flow task that copies the contents of one table to another table. Both the tables are from Azure SQL Server Managed Instance.

Comment: It works when I use Azure SQL database instead of Azure SQL Server Managed Instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through lot of documentation online, I have found that: SSIS Package execution through an SSIS Integration Runtime using a proxy supports only Data flows.

Refer Limitation section in the below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-proxy-ssis

To fix this I have create another SSIS Integration Runtime that joins the same VNet as Azure SQL Server Managed Instance.

Comment: Hi Karthik Doure,you can mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.

Comment: You could try again after few days.

Comment: Oh wow wish I could give this answer 100 votes!! Spent days trying to figure out why my SSIS packages fail in Azure, thanks so much for sharing.